# Animate surrounding elements movement when fadeToggle in jQuery

Tags: jquery, transition, element, duration

Is possible to animate objects which NOT affected (object of) by jQuery fadeToggle property?
Simply:

```js
$("#fadeOff_1").click(function(){
  $(".color1").fadeToggle("slow");
});
$("#fadeOff_2").click(function(){
  $(".color2").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #eee;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.box {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 1%;
  transition: move 1s; /* nope */
  
}
.color1 {background: teal;}
.color2 {background: #cf000f;}
.color3 {background:  #F39C12;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="fadeOff_1">Fade toggle first element</button>
<button type="button" id="fadeOff_2">Fade toggle second element</button>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box color1"></div>
<div class="box color2"></div>
 <div class="box color3"></div>
</div>
```

When the first button is pressed, it FadeOff the .color1 object (first box), but when fadeOff transition is finished, second object (.color2) 'jumps' into position of first, same story with second and third. How can I animate (transition-duration) the elements moving to left?

I want achieve something like this, but with fadeToggle:

```js
$("#fadeOff_1").click(function(){
  $(".color1").toggleClass("width");
});
$("#fadeOff_2").click(function(){
  $(".color2").toggleClass("width");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #eee;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.box {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 1%;
  transition: width 1s;
  
}
.box.width {
  width: 0;
}
.color1 {background: teal;}
.color2 {background: #cf000f;}
.color3 {background:  #F39C12;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="fadeOff_1">Width 0 first element</button>
<button type="button" id="fadeOff_2">Width 0 second element</button>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="box color1"></div>
<div class="box color2"></div>
 <div class="box color3"></div>
</div>
```

**I've found solution here on Stack Overflow, but I'm not looking for Opacity or Visibility fadeOff alternative.**